# Prolog List storage

Tags: prolog

I have a program which generates a list, and at different stages removes certain elements from it. There are 4 removal stages, and calling the 4th will first call 1,2,3 then 4. the predicate is called s4(Q, 100) and there are also s1, s2 ,s3 with the same preicate style, (Q,100).

At stage s1, I remove elements depending on how many factors they have, So i pass Q to another predicate, by calling

```
removePrimes(Q,L).
```

This now has the list Q minus the undesired elements. However, Q is unchanged and still has all the original elements.

My question is, is there a way of giving Q the result of L so it's value can be passed up to s2 to be altered again?

Here is the rest of my code so you can better see what I mean

```
s4(Q,X):-
    s3(Q,X).

s3(Q,X):-
    s2(Q,X).

s2(Q,X):-
    s1(Q,X).

    %Further alter the list here
    %Q is not passed back, since it is unchanged in s1

s1(Q,X):-
    s0(Q,X),
    %remove the undesired elements
    removePrimes(Q,L).

    %L now contains the list we need, but Q is unchanged!!!

s0(Q, N) :-
    %generate the list
    validPair(Q).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sTotal(L) :-
    validPair(Q),
    s1(Q, Q2),
    s2(Q2, Q3),
    s3(Q3, Q4),
    ...
    sN(QN, L).
```

should do the trick.

edit, going from your code:

```
s4(X, N):-
    s3(Q),
    dostuff(Q, X, N).

s3(L):-
    s2(Q),
    doblah(Q, L).

s2(L):-
    s1(Q),
    dosomethingwithalist(Q, L).

s1(L):-
    s0(Q),
    removePrimes(Q,L).
s0(Q) :-
    validPair(Q).
```

Note that this equivalent and a too verbose version of:

```
s4(X, N) :-
    validPair(Q),
    removePrimes(Q, Q2),
    dosomethingwithalist(Q2, Q3),
    doblah(Q3, Q4),
    dostuff(Q4, X, N).
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work for my situation, the program has to run by calling s4(Q,N), where N is an integer, so I can't use 2 lists to call the predicate. So if you call s4(Q,100) -> s3(Q,100) -> s2(Q,100) -> s1(Q,100) -> generateList -> make s1 changes to Q -> make s2 changes to Q -> make s3 changes to Q -> makes4 changes to Q -> print Q.

Comment: Ah of course! That makes perfect sense, thanks once again Mog!

Answer (score 1):

nope, prolog uses single assignment; you should pass the new list instead of the original.

well, some implementations (swi-prolog for example) support global variables that can be updated (or you can assert/retract) with but it's not really advised to use it, especially in this case

Comment: Hmm, there has to be some way the result of removePrimes(L) can get passed back up to s2?

Basically you call s4(Q,100), then it goes down through s3,s2,s1,makes s1 changes, makes s2 changes, makes s3 changes, makes s4 changes, then outputs Q, which should be the shortened list. How can I make this happen?